# Is it possible to send Blocks or Procs as arguments to Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a standard system for performing calculations on varied datasets.  What would be great is I could just pass those calculations as a Proc to the perform method.  Here's what I want to accomplish:

```
class Calculator
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform rails_model , rails_model_id
         obj = Kernel.const_get( rails_model ).find( rails_model_id )
         yield( obj )
    end
end

Calculator.perform_asyc( "User" , 123 , { |u| u.do_something } )
```

Is this sort of thing possible or is it bad practice?  I know that it's bad practice to send objects directly, so I'm assuming that sending blocks is also a bad idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that or no, but instead of using the Kernel module, why don't you:

`rails_model.constantize.find(rails_model_id)`

I'm hoping passing a block should not be a problem to Sidekiq.

Comment: Sidekiq runs the code in a separate process on a separate machine. Passing blocks will be problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no serialization format for code in Ruby, only for data.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can achieve this. I needed a worker to perform some operations on a collection of records but I wanted the flexibility to change the query on the model to return a different collection when needed.

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perfom(scoping_query)
    MyModel.class_eval(scoping_query).call.find_each do |m|
     # do stuff...
    end
  end    
end

MyWorker.perform_async("proc { where(attribute: value) }")
```

My solution would apply to your example like this.

```
class Calculator
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(klass, id, code_block)
    obj = klass.constantize.find(id)
    klass.constantize.class_eval(code_block).call(obj)
  end
end

Calculator.perform_asyc("User", 123, "proc { |u| u.do_something }")
```

As you can see the trick is to send the block as a string and then evaluate that string in the scope of the class which returns the Proc and then you can call it.